# Using .htaccess to redirect traffic from subpages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Im having a hard time trying to find a solution that works for my situation.

I want to redirect any visitors to my website to / using htaccess.

For example, if someone goes to www.example.com/thisisapage then it will redirect them back to /

But i need it for every page on my site automatically.

I have tried the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule $ / [R=302,L]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index
RewriteRule ^.+$ / [L,R]
```

This will redirect

- /foobar (excluding the dir index page)

to

- /

Comment: So if i want it to just go to / should i take out the index part?